# Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type `method group' and `method group'

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth

I am doing some BLE work in C#, where I want to go through a list of data and find the entry with a particular ID. However, the following code is throwing the error `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'method group'`. I have only come across this error when you are trying to compare two different types of data, why is it doing it with two types of the same data?

```
try {
    foreach(var data in services)
    {
        if (data!=null && data.ID.PartialFromUuid == 0xA001.UuidFromPartial){ GasSenseService = data; }

        Debug.WriteLineIf (data.Name == "Heart Rate", "SERVICE: data equals chosen value");
    }
}
catch {

    Debug.WriteLine ("Exception");
}
```

I am using the [`Monkey Robotics`](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/master/API%20Docs/Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE) nuget, which defines each data as an IService. `services` is an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory.  What don't you understand?  You're trying to compare two methods.  Methods cannot be compared to each other.

Comment: you have to invoke the method with putting `()` at end. so you are calling the overload that has no parameters you have to do this. even if there is only one overload that takes no parameters. when you write only name of the method it is considered method group. means the method and all of its overloads thus you cant compare them because it doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be with `data.ID.PartialFromUuid` `0xA001.UuidFromPartial`. I guess `0xA001` is an hex integer literal, and `PartialFromUuid` `UuidFromPartial` are extension methods. Change your code to *call the methods*!

```
if (data!=null && data.ID.PartialFromUuid() == 0xA001.UuidFromPartial())
```

In C# methods are called using `()` even if the method has no parameters.

In fact, I need to guess nothing. Check this source code file: https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/blob/master/Source/Platform%20Stacks/Robotics.Mobile.Core/Bluetooth/LE/Extensions.cs

```
public static Guid UuidFromPartial(this Int32 @partial) 
public static string PartialFromUuid(this Guid uuid)
```

***Yes, they're extension methods***.